# Which version of the app user gets after uninstalling version from staged rollout in Google Play and installing it again?

Tags: android, google-play

I have v2 in staged rollout and an old v1. User gets v2 because Google selected this user for stage rollout group. User uninstalls the app and installs it from Play Store again. Will it be v1 or v2 version this time?